# ngrok shows blank page when accessing a laravel project from a remote machine

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, portforwarding, ngrok

I am using ngrok to port-forward a website hosted locally on my machine. The website was built using Laravel, Vue and PHP. When I access it locally (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/`) everything works well.

When I run ngrok (`ngrok.exe http 8000`), I can access it from my local machine using the new link, but not from other machines. On the other devices, it seems that it loads the header of the website but nothing else.

This is the ngrok link: https://c3b8-2001-56a-fa70-ee00-d7b-a147-7d86-1c5a.ngrok-free.app/

Answer (score -2):

To configure ngrok with your Laravel application for local development, follow these steps:

- Open the `AppServiceProvider.php` file located in your Laravel project.
- Add the following code inside the `boot` method of the `AppServiceProvider` class:

  ```
  public function boot(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
  {
      if (!empty(env('NGROK_URL')) && $request->server->has('HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST')) {
          $this->app['url']->forceRootUrl(env('NGROK_URL'));
      }

      // Other code
  }
  ```
- Open your terminal and run the following command, replacing `laravel-site.test` with the local URL your Laravel app uses:

  ```
  ngrok http -host-header=rewrite laravel-site.test:80
  ```
- ngrok will provide you with a forwarding URL, typically in the format `abc123.ngrok.io`. Add the following line and replace abc123.ngrok.io with the URL you received from ngrok in the `.env` file:

  ```
  NGROK_URL=https://abc123.ngrok.io
  ```
- Clear your app's cache using the following commands in the terminal:

  ```
  php artisan config:clear
  php artisan cache:clear
  php artisan view:clear
  php artisan route:clear
  ```

For more: https://vanrossum.dev/5-using-ngrok-with-laravel

Comment: I followed all of your steps, and nothing changed. This is the new link: https://e8fd-2001-56a-fa70-ee00-d7b-a147-7d86-1c5a.ngrok-free.app/

Comment: Updated link: https://c3b8-2001-56a-fa70-ee00-d7b-a147-7d86-1c5a.ngrok-free.app/